# How to connect to oracle database as sysdba without user from java?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, database-connection

I can connect to Oracle in the following way: `sqlplus / as sysdba.` Can I connect in the same way from java? According to the docs (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/urls.htm#CHDJICFH), I have to have sys schema with the password, but I don't have any user.

Comment: most likely there 'll be a default pass and user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by Thin JDBC drivers.

When you execute `sqlplus / as sysdba` then your sqlplus spawns a child `oracle` process and then talks to it via pipe. So you completely bypass a network stack.

Comment: Thank you. It can be possible if I would use other drivers?